# Java generics - unexpected situation with Optional wrapping generics

Tags: java, generics

I have faced following situation:

```
import com.google.common.base.Optional;

public class CovarianceTest {

    class Race {
    }

    class Dog<Race> {
    }

    public Optional<Dog<? extends Race>> getDog() {
        Dog<? extends Race> dogWithSomeRace = new Dog();
        return Optional.of(dogWithSomeRace);
    }
}
```

Situation like this causes compilation problem. The IDE says:

```
Incompatible types.
Required: Optional<Dog<? extends Race>>
Found: Optional<? extends Dog<? extends Race>
```

Which is clearly wrong.

Could someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Dog<Race> is a problem. Race here is a Type, like T, not a Race class

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: did you mean `T extends Race` in the `Dog`? otherwise, all of this makes no sense

Comment: and which Java version are you using?

Comment: I can not reproduce in Java8. That is using the built in `Optional` type. You could try qualifying the call with the exact type: `Optional.<Dog<? extends Race>>of(dogWithSomeRace);`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you confused the class' generic type declaration with the boundary declaration of a generic type argument.

In your case:

```
class Race {}

class Dog<Race> {} // "Race" is declared as a generic type in dog. It's not referring to your Race class in any way.
```

Your definition of `Dog` is equivalent to

```
class Dog<E> {}
```

If you want to set a subclass of `Race` to be a generic boundary for `Dog`, then do for example

```
class Dog<E extends Race> {}
```

You could also refine the method's generic declarations:

```
public Optional<Dog<? extends Race>> // this could be shortend to Dog<?>, because Dog's boundary is already limited to Race in the class signature
                                     getDog() {
    Dog<? extends Race> dogWithSomeRace // This can be shortend aswell to Dog<?> 
                                        = new Dog(); // Missing type declaration in the constructor call 
    return Optional.of(dogWithSomeRace);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is your code:

1. Compiler thinks **Race** (in class `Dog<Race>`) is a type parameter that you will use for further parametrization of `class Dog`.
2. In the assignment `Dog<? extends Race> dogWithSomeRace = new Dog();` this is considered as not best practice.

[image]

I believe the code below is what you are trying to do. Use **T** as type parameter. Here we go:

```
import com.google.common.base.Optional;

public class CovarianceTest {

    class Race {
    }

    class Dog<T> {
        void whatever(T t) {
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    }

    public Optional<Dog<? extends Race>> getDog() {
        Dog<? extends Race> dogWithSomeRace = new Dog<Race>();
        return Optional.of(dogWithSomeRace);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println((new CovarianceTest()).getDog().isPresent());
        System.out.println((new CovarianceTest()).getDog().get().getClass());
    }
}
```

This prints nicely:

> true
>   class CovarianceTest$Dog

Comment: The JDK I use is 1.8.0_91. Unfortunatelly your solution does not work either, result is the same.

Comment: Hmmm... Well it runs on 1.8_102 and i think that JDK minor recision should not make much difference. Can you double check your code?